# How to modify databases using forms in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Im creating an app using Oracle Apex. I have 3 databases (Customers, Products and Orders) and each one has it own interactive form to modify information from them. However, after configurating the buttons (see the image below, it doesn´t works. I can´t add, erase or update any information. 
[image]

Comment: Hi Jesus, did Littlefoot's answer help, or are you still having difficulties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used Wizard (which - for each table - easily creates an Interactive Report **plus** DML Form), it creates everything that works properly. I suggest you do that.

If you created IR and Form manually, then it is not enough to set **database action** - you'll have to create appropriate **process** for those actions.

Finally, a remark: in Oracle, we have "tables", not "databases".